# What does capacity measure in logging's MemoryHandler?

Tags: python, logging

Python's [**`logging`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module has a buffered handler, [**`MemoryHandler`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#memoryhandler).

It takes a *`capacity`* parameter.

What are the units of *`capacity`*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capacity of the buffer is the number of entries it can hold. Each entry represents a logging event, corresponding to a call to a logger to log something.

Comment: So it gives a rough idea of memory usage if you know the average size of your logging events. Looking at [the source](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/logging/handlers.py), I noticed your name at the top and did a double take! Thanks very much.